# PyQt4 window crashes immediately on execution (OSX)

Tags: python, macos, pyqt4

I'm learning some PyQt4 and can't quite seem to get my first app off the ground.  Here's the code I'm using to make a simple window:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()

window.show()
```

Now, I've written this in a text editor and saved it as a .py file.  I go to Terminal and execute it as follows:

```
python exercise1.py
```

Once I do this, the Python icon appears and begins bouncing on my Dock (see the image)[image], only to immediately disappear.  The window never opens and Terminal returns to its normal state.  I've been Googling like crazy and can't quite seem to find a solution.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `window.show(); app.exec_()`.

Comment: @ekhumoro That did it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was what ekhumoro posted, I just needed to call

app.exec_()

at the end of the code.  D'oh!